# How do I make image load vertically upon opening the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I make my images load vertically upon opening the page? I know how to use HTML/CSS to make div elements fade into the page, but I was wondering how I could replace the header image loading vertically like in http://enod.fr/

Thank you! Sorry if this question is too vague. If someone could direct me to a codepen or jsfiddle link that I could work off of, that would also help a lot!

Comment: You mean like the text in enod fading upwards?

Comment: Hi Edward, sorry I wasn't specific enough -- I meant the image loading down vertically, before the words fade upwards! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a CSS animation. Here's a simple example showing how to use a background image on an element, and animate the height of that element to get the effect you want.

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent > div {
  height: 0px;
  background-image: url('http://enod.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/home.jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
  animation-name: load-vertically;
  animation-duration: 1.6s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: relative;
}

.parent > div > h1 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: delay-show;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}


@keyframes load-vertically {
  from {
    height: 0px;
  }
  
  to {
    height: 300px;
  }
}

@keyframes delay-show {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Brett, this helped a lot -- especially the text fading upwards after too!! :)

Comment: Instead of the animation starting immediately upon page load it would be  est to use JS to wait for the background image to load, then start the animation. Just an enhancement, not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with css @keyframes

```css
img{
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:100%;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    animation:slide_down 1s forwards;
    -webkit-animation:slide_down 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide_down{
    from{opacity:0;top:-100%}
    to{opacity:1;top:0%;}
    
}@-webkit-keyframes slide_down{
    from{opacity:0;top:-100%}
    to{opacity:1;top:0%;}
    
}
```

```html
<img src='http://enod.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/home.jpg'>
```